# Error in editing text file

Tags: python

I have a big file like the input and each 4 lines correspond to the same ID which is the line starting with @. the second line (after @) is a sequence of characters and for some of the IDs we do not have this line. if this is the case I would like to remove all 4 lines belong the same ID.
I also tried the code below in python and gave the error.

input:

```
@M00872:361:000000000-D2GK2:1:1101:16003:1351 1:N:0:1
ATCCGGCTCGGAGGA
+
1AA?ADDDADDAGGG
@M00872:361:000000000-D2GK2:1:1101:15326:1352 1:N:0:1
GCGCAGCGGAAGCGTGCTGGG
+
CCCCBCDCCCCCGGEGGGGGG
@M00872:361:000000000-D2GK2:1:1101:16217:1352 1:N:0:1

+
```

output:

```
@M00872:361:000000000-D2GK2:1:1101:16003:1351 1:N:0:1
ATCCGGCTCGGAGGA
+
1AA?ADDDADDAGGG
@M00872:361:000000000-D2GK2:1:1101:15326:1352 1:N:0:1
GCGCAGCGGAAGCGTGCTGGG
+
CCCCBCDCCCCCGGEGGGGGG


import fileinput

with fileinput.input(files="4415_pool.fastq", inplace=True, backup="file.bak") as f:
    for l in f:
        if l.strip().startswith("@"):
            c = 2
            next_line = f.readline().strip()  
            if not next_line:   
                while c:        
                    c -= 1
                    try:
                        next(f)
                    except StopIteration:
                        break
            else:
                print(l.strip())
                print(next_line.strip())
                while c:
                    c -= 1
                    try:
                        print(next(f).strip())
                    except StopIteration:
                        break
```

but did not work and gave this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: FileInput instance has no attribute '__exit__'
```

do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Which python version u are using? I think it is old version which not support fileinput to with. So use `f = fileinput.input(files="4415_pool_TCP_Ctrl.fastq", inplace=True, backup="file.bak")`

Comment: the version of python is:  2.7

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `fileinput.FileInput` class does not implement `__exit__()` method that is required if you want to use it in a `with fileinput.input()..` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think Problem is python version (2.7) which not support the fileinput to `with`

Use

```
f = fileinput.input(files="4415_pool.fastq", inplace=True, backup="file.bak")
```

Instead

```
with fileinput.input(files="4415_pool.fastq", inplace=True, backup="file.bak") as f
```

Answer (score 1):

although with statement was added in 2.5 , I don't think fileinput was ported to use it (contextlib?).

Your code will work in python3 but not in 2.7. To fix the issue, either use py3 or port your code to iterate over the lines like:

```
   with open(filename, "r") as f:
         lines = f.readlines()

   for line in lines: 
        #do whatever you need to do for each line.
```

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your question (in 2.7) I would do something like:

```
# Read all the lines in a buffer
with open('input.fastq', 'r') as source:
  source_buff = iter(source.readlines())

with open('output.fastq', 'w') as out_file:
  for line in source_buff:
    if line.strip().startswith('@'):
      prev_line = line
      line = next(source_buff)

      if line.strip():
        # if the 2nd line is not empty write the whole block in the output file
        out_file.write(prev_line)
        out_file.write(line)
        out_file.write(next(source_buff))
        out_file.write(next(source_buff))
      else:
        pass
```

I know .fastq files can be very big sometimes, so instead of reading the whole file in the buffer, I suggest to put this code in a loop where you read 4 lines (or as many lines as your block is) each time.